# Existing user creates new user in Supabase

Tags: reactjs, supabase

I am creating a front end app with ReactJS that uses Supabase for backend.

At the moment I am able to create users by `signUp()` function. All works fine but I am at the point that I want the existing user to be able to add new users but this seems impossible from the front end and I would like to know if there is any way it can be done.

There are some functions that can be used only from server side (`createUser()` and `inviteUserByEmail()`) but they need the `service_role` key and I wouldn't like it to be shown on the frontend.

Comment: With Next, the common practice is to create an api route that does have access to your service_role key (though your anon key should be sufficient), and have that route return the data you need on the frontend.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have figured it out that NextJS is capable of many things that only backend could do and I am really thing to start moving my code there. Do you know if stripe (which normally needs a backend) can work in NextJs withour a backend?